# nonlinear equation R

Tags: r, sas, nonlinear-functions

I like to fit a nonlinear equation(g and h are the parameters):

> q = g * (h**age)/(1 + g * (h**age));
>   restrict q = .05 when age = 50: 
>   i.e. g * (h**50)/(1 + g* (h**50)= .05.
>   This means when age = 50
>   the predicted value q equals the q in the data.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at  `nls()`  and/or the package `BB` .
But for real fun :-),  spend a little time with Eureqa, http://creativemachines.cornell.edu/eureqa .  You'll get more solutions than you ever thought possible!

Comment: Thank you for an interesting suggestion with Eureqa, Carl. Could you demonstrate the power of nls/BB (maybe even for a mock example)?

Comment: I think @Roland 's answer did the job for me.  But you're right: I should include dummy code as well as the package reference.

Answer (score 2):

```
#define function
qfun <- function(age,h){
  #the constraint can be added using algebra
  g <- 0.05/0.95/h^50 
  g * (h^age)/(1 + g * (h^age))
}     

#create data
age <- 1:75

h <- 0.75

q <- qfun(age,h) 
plot(q~age)
#add noise
q <- q+rnorm(length(q),sd=0.02)
plot(q~age)

#fit
fit <- nls(q~qfun(age,h),start=list(h=1))
summary(fit)
Formula: q ~ qfun(age, h)

#Parameters:
#  Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
#h 0.749644   0.001678   446.7   <2e-16 ***
#---
#Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1 
#
#Residual standard error: 0.01865 on 74 degrees of freedom
#
#Number of iterations to convergence: 5 
#Achieved convergence tolerance: 1.735e-06 
ttt<- function(x) qfun(x,coef(fit)[1])
curve(ttt,from=1,to=75,add=TRUE)
```

Comment: Does "g <- 0.05/0.95/h^50" means   "g * (h*50)/(1 + g (h**50)= .05"